# How we get close event of local notification?

Tags: iphone, background-process, uilocalnotification

I need to schedule local notification on receiving previously scheduling local notification. I have schedule another notification on close event of local notification.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to create a new local notification if "close" button in alert of UILocalnotification is clicked?

If so, you can't handle that close button event.

Comment: so can we have any background process like in android its have midnight day change event

Comment: so, can we add one extra button for handling some other user action?